# Am making a 32bit adder but "X" is outputted after every addition

Tags: verilog

Am very new to Verilog and am completely lost and don't know why this doesn't work, any help is appreciated.

Am making a 32bit adder by using only Half adders but I can't seem to make it work.
am using this site to test my code: https://www.edaplayground.com/

This is the part which I wrote that is not working:

```
//your code should start from here, don't touch inputs, don't touch other modules
genvar i;
genvar j;
   generate
     for(i=0; i<bitwidth; i=i+1) begin: block1
       if(i > 0)
         begin
           assign Temp_Cout = Adder_Cout;
         end
       for(j=i; j<bitwidth; j=j+1) begin:block2
         if(i == 0)
           begin
             HA inst_HA (A[j], B[j], Adder_S[j], Adder_Cout[j+1]);
           end
         else
           begin
             HA inst_HA (Adder_S[j], Temp_Cout[j], Adder_S[j], Adder_Cout[j+1]);
           end
       end
     end
   endgenerate
//your code should end here
```

Rest of the Code:

testbench.sv

```
// Code your testbench here
// or browse Examples
//don't touch anything in this file

module testbench();

parameter bitwidth = 32;

reg [bitwidth-1:0] numberA, numberB;
wire [bitwidth-1:0] answer;
reg clk=0;
wire lastCarry;

MyAdder adder_instance (clk, numberA, numberB, answer, lastCarry);

always #5 clk = ~clk;

initial begin

  $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); 
  $dumpvars(1);

    #100;

    #100;
  $display ("inputs were: 0, 0");
    numberA=0;
    numberB=0;
  #60 $display ("output is: %d",answer);

    #100;
  $display ("inputs were: 7, 39");
    numberA=7;
    numberB=39;
  #60 $display ("output is: %d",answer);

    #100;
  $display ("inputs were: 1, 3");
    numberA=1;
    numberB=3;
  #60 $display ("output is: %d",answer);

    #100;
  $display ("inputs were: 3, 7");
    numberA=3;
    numberB=7;
  #60 $display ("output is: %d",answer);

    #100;
  $display ("inputs were: 1596, 48621");
    numberA=1596;
    numberB=48621;
  #60 $display ("output is: %d",answer);

    #100;
  $display ("inputs were: 4294967295, 1");
    numberA=4294967295;
    numberB=1;
  #60 $display ("output is: %d",answer);

    #100;

    $finish;

end
endmodule
```

design.sv

```
// Code your design here
module MyAdder
#(
    parameter bitwidth = 32
)(
    input clk,
    input [bitwidth-1:0] A, B,
    output [bitwidth-1:0] S,
    output Cout
);
//you can change this two lines
    wire [bitwidth:1] Adder_Cout;
    wire [bitwidth:1] Temp_Cout;
    wire [bitwidth-1:0] Adder_S;
    
//your code should start from here, don't touch inputs, don't touch other modules
    genvar i;
    genvar j;
       generate
         for(i=0; i<bitwidth; i=i+1) begin: block1
           if(i > 0)
             begin
               assign Temp_Cout = Adder_Cout;
             end
           for(j=i; j<bitwidth; j=j+1) begin:block2
             if(i == 0)
               begin
                 HA inst_HA (A[j], B[j], Adder_S[j], Adder_Cout[j+1]);
               end
             else
               begin
                 HA inst_HA (Adder_S[j], Temp_Cout[j], Adder_S[j], Adder_Cout[j+1]);
               end
           end
         end
       endgenerate
//your code should end here


//but you can also change this two lines
    assign S = Adder_S;
    assign Cout = Adder_Cout[bitwidth];
endmodule


module HA(
    input a,b,
    output s, cout
);
    assign s=a^b;
    assign cout=a&b;
endmodule

module FA (
    input a,b,cin,
    output s,cout
    );
    wire xor1;
    assign xor1 = a^b;
    assign s = xor1^cin;
    assign cout = xor1&cin | a&b;
endmodule
```

This is the output am getting:
[image]

this is what am trying to create:
[image]

4bit adder with this logic which I made on logic.ly:
[image]

Comment: Use the simulation! Trace the signals through bit 0 to figure out what causes the x.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in your second HA instantiation, in the else branch of the always block. You've got the same signal as an input and an output of a combinational logic block. You probably want the output to use the index + 1.

Comment: unfortunately that's not the issue :\

Comment: Well it's definitely part of the problem. Double check all the indices. And as the other commenter suggested, look at the waves from your simulation. My guess is thst bit 0 of your sum is not X but the other bits are.